# Jquery clear select in the second populate

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this jquery and it is working fine. but the problem that i am facing when i select second time it will add the data to the previous results. and will not clear it. 
I tried to use empty function and .html('') but it did not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  $("#cat").change(function(){
$.ajax(
{url:"maintenance_task.php",
data:   { cat_id : $("#cat option:selected").val() },
dataType: 'json',
success:function(json){
     $.each(json, function(i, value) {

        $('#task_type').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', i));
    });
  }});  });});
```

can anybody help me with this. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('#task_type').empty()` at the start of the `success` function didn't work?

Comment: Ya $('#task_type').empty() but outside the each loop

Comment: yes it did work i added it inside the each loop. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
 $("#cat").change(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url:"maintenance_task.php",
      data:   { cat_id : $("#cat option:selected").val() },
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(json){
        $('#task_type').html(' ');
        $.each(json, function(i, value) {
          $('#task_type').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', i));
        });
     }
  }); 
 });
});
```